# When can a local undo result in empty redo stack?

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

I've tried for a couple hours to recreate the problem I'm having in a simpler context than my app, with no success, so hopefully the following description will be enough.

1. One collaborator (me), and this happens both online and in in-memory mode.
2. Start a compound operation.
3. Some processing happens to choose what simple ops to put in the compound op. There are many nested function calls, but AFAIK they're all in one synchronous execution block, and I don't get the "Open compound operation at end of synchronous block" exception.
4. The chosen simple ops are done.
5. End the compound operation.
6. Call model.undo() from the terminal, and my app behaves as-expected.
7. But now model.canRedo is false, so model.redo() throws an error citing the empty redo stack.

I tried the same sequence of API calls aside from (3), in a script outside of my app, and everything works (i.e. at (7), model.canRedo is true, and model.redo() has the expected result). My only other clue is that when I do the steps within my app, (6) causes the Model's serverRevision and serverVersion to increase by 2, whereas in the script outside my app, the undo causes those fields to increase by 1.

Using the Realtime debugger shows the 4 edit ops that compose my compound op, which inserts something like this:

```
{ // new CollaborativeMap
    'ch': [] // new CollaborativeList
    'nch': {}  // new CollaborativeMap
    'nodetype': 'Outline'
}
```

into an existing CollaborativeList at index 2. The debugger displays 4 edit events:

```
{nodetype: "Outline", ch: [], nch: {}} was added at index 2.
nch has changed from null to {}.
ch has changed from null to [].
nodetype has changed from null to Outline.
```

Then I undo, and the debugger (somewhat confusingly) shows only this 1 edit event:

```
{} was removed at index 2.
```

I'm guessing there were edit events removing values from the map that aren't shown? Anyway, the problem is that after that undo op, the redo stack is empty.

Comment: I can't think of any scenarios where you, with local-only changes, you should be able to undo and then not redo.  You could try using the debugger to see exactly what is changing when you get into this state: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/debugger

Comment: @CherylSimon thanks for your help as always - this is the first time I've had the reputation points to respond in a comment.

I was using the debugger. I added my experience with it to the question.

Comment: Well, I accidentally found a workaround. When I removed the creation of the outermost CollaborativeMap from the compound op (doing it just before beginCompoundOperation instead), the results are surprisingly more-or-less what I wanted. The debugger shows only one edit event message `{nodetype: "Outline", ch: [], nch: {}} was added at index 2.`. And then for the undo: `{nodetype: "Outline", ch: [], nch: {}}` was removed at index 2.`. And the redo displays the first message again.